# Multiline column headers in .NET4 WinForm Listview

Tags: .net, winforms, listview

I have a listview in Details view and I have added columns. I would like to have the column header increase in height and either word-wrap the header text or allow me to specify the line break using a CrLf.

Is this possible using the standard .NET controls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's difficult, you cannot control the column header height directly.  You can do it indirectly by giving the ListView a big Font.  You then need to set the OwnerDraw property to true and implement the DrawItem, DrawSubItem and DrawColumnHeader events.  The latter lets you word-wrap the text.  You will also need to set the Font property for each ListViewItem you add so they are not drawn large as well.  Unpleasant but not impossible.

Answer (score -1):

[Better ListView control](http://www.componentowl.com/better-listview) does just this and it is written pure managed (.NET) code.

Both column headers and items (and even group headers) can contain arbitrary multi-line text, even with custom line breaks. Maximum number of lines can be limited by a property:

[image]

[image]